# ¿Cómo compartir variables / información entre 2 o más threads en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, hilos

Cuando tengo scripts que tienen que realizar búsquedas intensas, generalmente divido el trabajo en *threads* con ayuda del módulo `threading`. Ya que mi programa principal es el que está a cargo de las búsquedas, también este programa principal debería estar a cargo de ofrecer los resultados al usuario, no los *threads*.

A manera de ejemplo, supongamos que tengo un script, el cual se encarga de saber si un número está dentro del rango de 1 y 1 mil millones. Cada *thread* esta realizando comparaciones y puede ser que encuentre el resultado.

Mi script de ejemplo se ve algo así:

```
import threading
def busqueda1(num):
    for i in range(500000000):
        if(num == i):
            print("Busqueda1 confirmó el número")
def busqueda2(num):
    for i in range(500000001,1000000000):
        if(num == i):
            print("Busqueda2 confirmó el número")
numero = 123456789
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=busqueda1,args=(numero,))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=busqueda2,args=(numero,))
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

Lo que necesito es saber en mi programa principal cual de los dos *threads* ha encontrado el número y mostrárselo al usuario.

Ya que son hilos de ejecución diferentes, ¿cómo hago que el programa principal y otros *threads* puedan tener acceso a los posibles resultados que se estan generando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De la [documentación oficial de python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html) sabemos que el objeto `Queue`:

> "Is especially useful in threaded programming when information must
>   be exchanged safely between multiple threads."
>
> (Mi traducción libre: 
>   "Es especialmente útil en programación con hilos cuando la información
>   debe intercambiarse de forma segura entre multiples hilos.")

De manera que la respuesta para esta pregunta es usar un objeto `Queue` para intercambiar la información entre los hilos. A manera breve, `Queue` es un objeto que simula una cola. Cuando se instancia, por defecto se inicializa como "primero en entrar, primero en salir", lo cual indica que el primer objeto que introduzcamos en la cola será el primer objeto que obtengamos cuando intentemos sacar algo de allí.

El código se vería algo así:

```
import threading
import queue
def busqueda1(num,cola):
    for i in range(500000000):
        if(num == i):
            cola.put("Busqueda1 confirmó el número")
def busqueda2(num,cola):
    for i in range(500000001,1000000000):
        if(num == i):
            cola.put("Busqueda2 confirmó el número")
numero = 123456789
cola = queue.Queue()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=busqueda1,args=(numero,cola))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=busqueda2,args=(numero,cola))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print(cola.get())
```

Entonces, en vez de imprimir en pantalla, los *threads* ponen en la cola el resultado que obtienen y el programa principal puede acceder a esta cola y obtener la información de allí e imprimirla.

Esta respuesta y pregunta estan inspiradas en [esta pregunta del sitio en ingles.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461413/how-to-share-a-variable-between-2-threads)